# Remove/Hide image tag of CButtonColumn

Tags: yii, cbuttoncolumn

I am using `CGridview` and in `CButtonColumn` and i am using css to set button images. Is it possible to hide/remove the image tag produce by class?

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the xButtonImageUrl to `false` to avoid rendering the img tag:

```
array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'deleteButtonImageUrl'=>false,
    'updateButtonImageUrl'=>false,
    'viewButtonImageUrl'=>false
)
```

Check [this part](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#deleteButtonImageUrl-detail) in documentation:

> the image URL for the delete button. If not set, an integrated image will be used. You may set this property to be false to render a text link instead.

Comment: let me know if you need any clarifications

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to do it via css?

```
.buttonClass {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is may be old. But still can be useful to someone. 
Just comment out the `imageUrl` array element.

```
'delete' => array
            (
                'label'=>'Delete',
                //'imageUrl'=>'',
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("users/delete",array("id"=>$data->id))',                  
            )
```